# WCF Bidirectional serialization fails

Tags: wcf, linq-to-sql, serialization, bidirectional

I'm trying to take advantage of Bidirectional serialization of some relational Linq-2-Sql generated entity classes. When using Unidirectional option everything works just fine, bu the moment I add IsReferenceType=true, objects fail to get transported over the tcp binding.
Sample code:
Entity class:

```
[Table(Name="dbo.Blocks")]
    [DataContract()]
    public partial class Block : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

        private long _ID;

        private int _StatusID;

        private string _Name;

        private bool _IsWithControlPoints;

        private long _DivisionID;

        private string _SHAPE;

        private EntitySet<BlockByWorkstation> _BlockByWorkstations;

        private EntitySet<PlanningPointAppropriation> _PlanningPointAppropriations;

        private EntitySet<Neighbor> _Neighbors;

        private EntitySet<Neighbor> _Neighbors1;

        private EntitySet<Task> _Tasks;

        private EntitySet<PlanningPointByBlock> _PlanningPointByBlocks;

        private EntitySet<ControlPointByBlock> _ControlPointByBlocks;

        private EntityRef<Division> _Division;

        private bool serializing;

    #region Extensibility Method Definitions
    partial void OnLoaded();
    partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action);
    partial void OnCreated();
    partial void OnIDChanging(long value);
    partial void OnIDChanged();
    partial void OnStatusIDChanging(int value);
    partial void OnStatusIDChanged();
    partial void OnNameChanging(string value);
    partial void OnNameChanged();
    partial void OnIsWithControlPointsChanging(bool value);
    partial void OnIsWithControlPointsChanged();
    partial void OnDivisionIDChanging(long value);
    partial void OnDivisionIDChanged();
    partial void OnSHAPEChanging(string value);
    partial void OnSHAPEChanged();
    #endregion

        public Block()
        {
            this.Initialize();
        }

        [Column(Storage="_ID", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="BigInt NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
        [DataMember(Order=1)]
        public override long ID
        {
            get
            {
                return this._ID;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._ID != value))
                {
                    this.OnIDChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    this._ID = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("ID");
                    this.OnIDChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        [Column(Storage="_StatusID", DbType="Int NOT NULL")]
        [DataMember(Order=2)]
        public int StatusID
        {
            get
            {
                return this._StatusID;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._StatusID != value))
                {
                    this.OnStatusIDChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    this._StatusID = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("StatusID");
                    this.OnStatusIDChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        [Column(Storage="_Name", DbType="NVarChar(255)")]
        [DataMember(Order=3)]
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Name;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._Name != value))
                {
                    this.OnNameChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    this._Name = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("Name");
                    this.OnNameChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        [Column(Storage="_IsWithControlPoints", DbType="Bit NOT NULL")]
        [DataMember(Order=4)]
        public bool IsWithControlPoints
        {
            get
            {
                return this._IsWithControlPoints;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._IsWithControlPoints != value))
                {
                    this.OnIsWithControlPointsChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    this._IsWithControlPoints = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("IsWithControlPoints");
                    this.OnIsWithControlPointsChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        [Column(Storage="_DivisionID", DbType="BigInt NOT NULL")]
        [DataMember(Order=5)]
        public long DivisionID
        {
            get
            {
                return this._DivisionID;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._DivisionID != value))
                {
                    if (this._Division.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue)
                    {
                        throw new System.Data.Linq.ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException();
                    }
                    this.OnDivisionIDChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    this._DivisionID = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("DivisionID");
                    this.OnDivisionIDChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        [Column(Storage="_SHAPE", DbType="Text", UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
        [DataMember(Order=6)]
        public string SHAPE
        {
            get
            {
                return this._SHAPE;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._SHAPE != value))
                {
                    this.OnSHAPEChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    this._SHAPE = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("SHAPE");
                    this.OnSHAPEChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        [Association(Name="Block_BlockByWorkstation", Storage="_BlockByWorkstations", ThisKey="ID", OtherKey="BlockID")]
        [DataMember(Order=7, EmitDefaultValue=false)]
        public EntitySet<BlockByWorkstation> BlockByWorkstations
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.serializing 
                            && (this._BlockByWorkstations.HasLoadedOrAssignedValues == false)))
                {
                    return null;
                }
                return this._BlockByWorkstations;
            }
            set
            {
                this._BlockByWorkstations.Assign(value);
            }
        }

        [Association(Name="Block_PlanningPointAppropriation", Storage="_PlanningPointAppropriations", ThisKey="ID", OtherKey="MasterBlockID")]
        [DataMember(Order=8, EmitDefaultValue=false)]
        public EntitySet<PlanningPointAppropriation> PlanningPointAppropriations
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.serializing 
                            && (this._PlanningPointAppropriations.HasLoadedOrAssignedValues == false)))
                {
                    return null;
                }
                return this._PlanningPointAppropriations;
            }
            set
            {
                this._PlanningPointAppropriations.Assign(value);
            }
        }

        [Association(Name="Block_Neighbor", Storage="_Neighbors", ThisKey="ID", OtherKey="FirstBlockID")]
        [DataMember(Order=9, EmitDefaultValue=false)]
        public EntitySet<Neighbor> Neighbors
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.serializing 
                            && (this._Neighbors.HasLoadedOrAssignedValues == false)))
                {
                    return null;
                }
                return this._Neighbors;
            }
            set
            {
                this._Neighbors.Assign(value);
            }
        }

        [Association(Name="Block_Neighbor1", Storage="_Neighbors1", ThisKey="ID", OtherKey="SecondBlockID")]
        [DataMember(Order=10, EmitDefaultValue=false)]
        public EntitySet<Neighbor> Neighbors1
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.serializing 
                            && (this._Neighbors1.HasLoadedOrAssignedValues == false)))
                {
                    return null;
                }
                return this._Neighbors1;
            }
            set
            {
                this._Neighbors1.Assign(value);
            }
        }

        [Association(Name="Block_Task", Storage="_Tasks", ThisKey="ID", OtherKey="BlockID")]
        [DataMember(Order=11, EmitDefaultValue=false)]
        public EntitySet<Task> Tasks
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.serializing 
                            && (this._Tasks.HasLoadedOrAssignedValues == false)))
                {
                    return null;
                }
                return this._Tasks;
            }
            set
            {
                this._Tasks.Assign(value);
            }
        }

        [Association(Name="Block_PlanningPointByBlock", Storage="_PlanningPointByBlocks", ThisKey="ID", OtherKey="BlockID")]
        [DataMember(Order=12, EmitDefaultValue=false)]
        public EntitySet<PlanningPointByBlock> PlanningPointByBlocks
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.serializing 
                            && (this._PlanningPointByBlocks.HasLoadedOrAssignedValues == false)))
                {
                    return null;
                }
                return this._PlanningPointByBlocks;
            }
            set
            {
                this._PlanningPointByBlocks.Assign(value);
            }
        }

        [Association(Name="Block_ControlPointByBlock", Storage="_ControlPointByBlocks", ThisKey="ID", OtherKey="BlockID")]
        [DataMember(Order=13, EmitDefaultValue=false)]
        public EntitySet<ControlPointByBlock> ControlPointByBlocks
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.serializing 
                            && (this._ControlPointByBlocks.HasLoadedOrAssignedValues == false)))
                {
                    return null;
                }
                return this._ControlPointByBlocks;
            }
            set
            {
                this._ControlPointByBlocks.Assign(value);
            }
        }

        [Association(Name="Division_Block", Storage="_Division", ThisKey="DivisionID", OtherKey="ID", IsForeignKey=true, DeleteOnNull=true, DeleteRule="CASCADE")]
        public Division Division
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Division.Entity;
            }
            set
            {
                Division previousValue = this._Division.Entity;
                if (((previousValue != value) 
                            || (this._Division.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue == false)))
                {
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    if ((previousValue != null))
                    {
                        this._Division.Entity = null;
                        previousValue.Blocks.Remove(this);
                    }
                    this._Division.Entity = value;
                    if ((value != null))
                    {
                        value.Blocks.Add(this);
                        this._DivisionID = value.ID;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this._DivisionID = default(long);
                    }
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("Division");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void SendPropertyChanging()
        {
            if ((this.PropertyChanging != null))
            {
                this.PropertyChanging(this, emptyChangingEventArgs);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            if ((this.PropertyChanged != null))
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        private void attach_BlockByWorkstations(BlockByWorkstation entity)
        {
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            entity.Block = this;
        }

        private void detach_BlockByWorkstations(BlockByWorkstation entity)
        {
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            entity.Block = null;
        }

        private void attach_PlanningPointAppropriations(PlanningPointAppropriation entity)
        {
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            entity.Block = this;
        }

        private void detach_PlanningPointAppropriations(PlanningPointAppropriation entity)
        {
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            entity.Block = null;
        }

        private void attach_Neighbors(Neighbor entity)
        {
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            entity.FirstBlock = this;
        }

        private void detach_Neighbors(Neighbor entity)
        {
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            entity.FirstBlock = null;
        }

        private void attach_Neighbors1(Neighbor entity)
        {
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            entity.SecondBlock = this;
        }

        private void detach_Neighbors1(Neighbor entity)
        {
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            entity.SecondBlock = null;
        }

        private void attach_Tasks(Task entity)
        {
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            entity.Block = this;
        }

        private void detach_Tasks(Task entity)
        {
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            entity.Block = null;
        }

        private void attach_PlanningPointByBlocks(PlanningPointByBlock entity)
        {
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            entity.Block = this;
        }

        private void detach_PlanningPointByBlocks(PlanningPointByBlock entity)
        {
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            entity.Block = null;
        }

        private void attach_ControlPointByBlocks(ControlPointByBlock entity)
        {
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            entity.Block = this;
        }

        private void detach_ControlPointByBlocks(ControlPointByBlock entity)
        {
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            entity.Block = null;
        }

        private void Initialize()
        {
            this._BlockByWorkstations = new EntitySet<BlockByWorkstation>(new Action<BlockByWorkstation>(this.attach_BlockByWorkstations), new Action<BlockByWorkstation>(this.detach_BlockByWorkstations));
            this._PlanningPointAppropriations = new EntitySet<PlanningPointAppropriation>(new Action<PlanningPointAppropriation>(this.attach_PlanningPointAppropriations), new Action<PlanningPointAppropriation>(this.detach_PlanningPointAppropriations));
            this._Neighbors = new EntitySet<Neighbor>(new Action<Neighbor>(this.attach_Neighbors), new Action<Neighbor>(this.detach_Neighbors));
            this._Neighbors1 = new EntitySet<Neighbor>(new Action<Neighbor>(this.attach_Neighbors1), new Action<Neighbor>(this.detach_Neighbors1));
            this._Tasks = new EntitySet<Task>(new Action<Task>(this.attach_Tasks), new Action<Task>(this.detach_Tasks));
            this._PlanningPointByBlocks = new EntitySet<PlanningPointByBlock>(new Action<PlanningPointByBlock>(this.attach_PlanningPointByBlocks), new Action<PlanningPointByBlock>(this.detach_PlanningPointByBlocks));
            this._ControlPointByBlocks = new EntitySet<ControlPointByBlock>(new Action<ControlPointByBlock>(this.attach_ControlPointByBlocks), new Action<ControlPointByBlock>(this.detach_ControlPointByBlocks));
            this._Division = default(EntityRef<Division>);
            OnCreated();
        }

        [OnDeserializing()]
        [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        public void OnDeserializing(StreamingContext context)
        {
            this.Initialize();
        }

        [OnSerializing()]
        [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        public void OnSerializing(StreamingContext context)
        {
            this.serializing = true;
        }

        [OnSerialized()]
        [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        public void OnSerialized(StreamingContext context)
        {
            this.serializing = false;
        }
    }
```

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="debugging"
        name="DBServicesLibrary.DBService">              
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DBServicesLibrary.DBServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>

          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="debugging">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Host part:

```
ServiceHost svh = new ServiceHost(typeof(DBService));
            svh.AddServiceEndpoint(
                typeof(DBServices.Contract.IDBService),
                new NetTcpBinding(),
                "net.tcp://localhost:8000");
```

Client part:

```
ChannelFactory<DBServices.Contract.IDBService> scf;
            scf = new ChannelFactory<DBServices.Contract.IDBService>(new NetTcpBinding(),"net.tcp://localhost:8000");


            _serv = scf.CreateChannel();
            ((IContextChannel)_serv).OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[L2ST4](http://l2st4.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=79965) will help you.

and I quote...

"LINQ to SQL supports the basic DataContract serialization out of the box. This basic serialization had no mechanism to tell it which end of an association was the owner to prevent serialization getting stuck in a loop and so LINQ to SQL would only serialize one side of the relationship."

Comment: The L2ST4 merely adds the IsReference=True attribute to each one of the generated classes, doesn't it?
I've done it myself and experienced the same problem.
After downloading the template and applying it the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to just add IsReferenceType=true to your DataContract attribute.  You also have to make sure all properties have the DataMember attribute.  When you set the serialization mode to unidirectional it only automatically adds the DataMember attribute in one direction.  For example, it will automatically put the attribute on Group.Users, but you will have to add it to User.Group yourself.  I recently tried manually adding in IsReferenceType=true and DataMember and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I followed your advice but it didn't help either.
In my case there is an object called Block and an object called Task.
The relationship is 1->many (one block -> many tasks).
The Tasks property of the block serializes alright but the Block property of the Task fails to deserialize even after adding the aforementioned attributes manually...